# InstallTrigger.install is not working in Firefox 4 while using -chrome. Any work arounds?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I work on an application that runs in chrome mode in Firefox (fx.exe -chrome chrome://app/content/main.xul). Prior to Firefox 4 (3.6 and below) I used the InstallTrigger.install to upgrade the application when there was a new version available.

Unfortunately, this no longer works in Firefox 4. Has anyone else run into this problem? How did you get around it?

Answer (score 1):

To work around the issue we used the AddOnManager API in the place of InstallTrigger.

For more information see [XUL Dev Add-On Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager)

```
Components.utils['import']("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");

AddonManager.getInstallForURL(xpi_address, function(addon) {
    addon.addListener({
        onDownloadStarted: function() {
            alert('Download Started');
        }
      });
      addon.addListener({
        onDownloadProgress: function() {
            var complete_percent = parseInt((100 * (addon.progress/addon.maxProgress)),10);
        }
      });
      addon.addListener({
        onDownloadFailed: function() {
            alert('Upgrade Failed');
        }
      });
      addon.addListener({
        onDownloadEnded: function() {
            alert('Download Successful');
        }
      });
      addon.addListener({
        onInstallStarted: function() {
            alert('Install Started');
        }
      });
      addon.addListener({
        onInstallEnded: function() {
            alert('Install Successful');
        }
      });
      addon.addListener({
        onInstallFailed: function() {
            alert('Install Failed');
        }
      });
      addon.install();
    }, "application/x-xpinstall");
```